# Why freeing not empty TList<Int64> does not cause memory leak?

Tags: delphi, generics, memory-leaks, int64, tlist

Freeing not empty `TList<Integer>` does not cause memory leak because Integer is equal to pointer in size, and TList handles pointers perfectly. (This is as far as I understand it.) Freeing not empty `TList<String>` also does not cause memory leak, as String itself is a pointer and is carefully freed somewhere in Delphi's internals when it's no longer needed.

However, freeing any not empty `TList<SomeClass>` always produces memory leak, and it's understood why.

The thing I do not understand is why freeing not empty `TList<Int64>` does not produce memory leak.

Sorry for the noob question.

Comment: Outside of any list, do you have to free an `Int64`?

Comment: @Jerry Dodge. No, never.

Comment: Well, that's why. Same with an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `TList<T>` is simply a wrapper around a dynamic array of `T`. A dynamic array of `T` is a managed type and so does not need explicit destruction.

This leaves the elements of the array. Since `Int64` is a value type, it needs no explicit destruction.

As a general rule, you need only destroy that which you created. You created the list, you need to destroy it. You did not create the elements themselves, so you do not need to destroy them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification. Surely, I confused types and classes.

Comment: @LURD It's anything other than a class in a desktop compiler right? Struggling for words here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't agree with your definition of general rule. Why? It is possible that by calling sone API the API itself creates some object and then simply returns reference or handle to that object as a result to you. In such case you will still have to destroy that object after you finish using it. But you din't create it. Well not directly. My general rule is that whenever you are accesing some data throuh a reference you need to destroy it at some time.

Comment: @Silver A string is a reference. So is an interface. It's just unmanaged reference types.